# Regex - look-behind requires fixed-width pattern error

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

**Code:**

```
text = "('hel'lo') eq 'some 'variable he're'"
re.compile(r"(?<!\(|(?<=eq ))'(?!\)|\Z)").sub(string=text, repl="''")
```

**Getting error:**

```
re.error: look-behind requires fixed-width pattern
```

**Expected output**:

('hel''lo') eq 'some ''variable he''re'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to assert that what is on the left is not `eq`  it should be a negative lookbehind `(?<!` instead of a positive lookbehind.

You can write the pattern using 2 lookbehind assertions.

```
(?<!\()(?<!eq )'(?!\)|\Z)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/U5qdo0/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/9Uixff)

Example code

```
import re
text = "('hel'lo') eq 'some 'variable he're'"
print(re.compile(r"(?<!\()(?<!eq )'(?!\)|\Z)").sub(string=text, repl="''"))
```

Output

```
('hel''lo') eq 'some ''variable he''re'
```

Comment: I was trying to use ALTERNATIVES which was causing me the error. Two Look behind also works.. thank you very much